# magento 2 : How do I set display stock status to don't show?

Tags: magento2, inventory

I need  the "in inventory" message not to be displayed, with products set to don't manage stock.

Comment: Can you describe in some more details what you are looking for?

Comment: Here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/348481/magento-2-stock-display-question

Comment: I posted answer on that one, Kindly check.