# Magento 2. Stock display question

Tags: magento2, stock-status, manage-stock

Is there a way to implement desired logic ?

In stock --> display  "in Stock" and product can be added to cart

Out of stock -> does not display any message and product can be added to cart

Answer (score 0):

For this one you need to do the following things.

1. To Show the Out Of Stock product into frontend, you need to do this things :

> Go to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options

`Display Out of Stock Products`: Choose Yes to enable displaying out of stock products in the frontend.

2. Enable the `Backorder` for the product, so it will allowed Out of Stock product to added to cart.

   A. On the Admin sidebar, go to `Stores > Settings > Configuratio`n.

   B. Set Store View to Default Config.

   C. In the left panel, expand `Catalog` and choose `Inventory`.

   D. Expand `Product Stock Options`.

   E. For `Backorders`, deselect the `Use system value checkbox` and select an option according to your requirement.

   F. For `Out-of-Stock Threshold`, deselect the `Use system value checkbox` and enter a different amount according to your requirement.
3. Now For that message, you need to overide that template file into your extension and do the things according to requirement.

Comment: Can you be more specific on point 3 ?

Comment: The Stock informatino is show usig one phtml file, you need to overide that phtml file into your third party extension and then do the custom coding there.